# Is there a more efficient way to set images to UIImageView?

Tags: swift

I program alone. I've been teaching myself for 6 months now. Because there's no one around to ask there are some very basic things to which I wonder if they could be done more efficiently, i.e. more efficient on memory, concise/clearer to write, etc. One of the patterns I find myself repeating often is this type of `for-loop` to set properties for objects...

```
var userCategoryWins = [String] //filled with data from whatever source

var userCategory1 = UIImageView()
var userCategory2 = UIImageView()
var userCategory3 = UIImageView()
var userCategory4 = UIImageView()

    let userCategoryArray = [userCategory1, userCategory2, userCategory3, userCategory4]

    for index in 0..<userCategoryWins.count {

        let imageView = userCategoryArray[index]
        imageView.hidden = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "leader\(userCategoryWins[index])")

    }
```

Assuming that there has to be order to which images are being assigned to each imageView, it's not just the same image, Is there a "better" way to do this, or would this be considered sufficient in a professional environment?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is good enough, but I would be inclined to store the Image Views in an array or outlet collection from the outset instead of making one on the fly.

Also you can have fun with `zip` in this context:

```
for (win, imageView) in zip(userCategoryWins, userCategoryArray) {
    imageView.hidden = false
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "leader\(win)")
}
```

It's a little cleaner IMHO, and it makes the connection between the two arrays more obvious.